# Why is my inline arrow function not changing states as expected?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I had a function declared inline and had to remove it because it yielded unexpected results.

```
RadioListTile<Wealth>(
              title: Text("Rich"),
              value: Wealth.RICH,
              groupValue: state,
              onChanged: (newValue) => changeStatus,
            )

void changeStatus(Wealth newValue) {
setState(() {
  state = newValue;
});
}
```

That code didn't work, but once I changed it to this it worked..

```
RadioListTile<Wealth>(
              title: Text("Rich"),
              value: Wealth.RICH,
              groupValue: state,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                if (newValue == null) return;
                changeStatus(newValue);
              },
            )
```

What is the difference between the two and why didn't the first code snippet work? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet yielded unexpected results because when you do

```
onChanged: (newValue) => changeStatus,
```

you're creating a lambda that accepts a parameter `newValue` and returns the function `changeStatus`, without actually calling it.

This should be replaced to

```
onChanged: (newValue) => changeStatus(newValue),
```

or

```
onChanged: changeStatus,
```

---

However, if you have null-safety on, this will still raise an error because the function type of `onChanged` is `void Function(Wealth?)`, while your `changeStatus` function type is `void Function(Wealth)`. To fix this, just change your `changeStatus` function to

```
void changeStatus(Wealth? newValue) {
  if (newValue == null) return;
  setState(() {
    state = newValue;
  });
}
```